# API for Dictionary and Translator

Tags: api, execute

Again. I've been searching for the best API for my Application. Dictionary and Translator. Can someone Recommend One. Please. i need it. I downloaded "microsoft-translator-jar" and I'm having an error in my line of code.

```
 'com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.execute(text, Language.ENGLISH, Language.ITALIAN);'
```

The error is at the (execute). the method execute(String,Language,Language)in the type Translate is not applicable for the arguments (String, Language, Language).
i've tried all the execute methods but No luck. Can someone help me how to solve it or refer a new API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be lost [json-simple-1.x.jar](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/). 
Please go website http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ to download that package.
I think your problem may be resolved.

Good-luck!